# Slicing list the other way around?

Tags: python, slice

I have this list:

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

What I wanted to do is make a new list with values from index 5 to index 1.

Output would be:

```
[6, 1, 2]
```

This is what I've done:

```
output = arr[5:] + arr[:2]
```

But I wanted to know if there's another way of slicing it.

Like just a normal slicing like for example:

```
output = arr[5:1]
```

But I know it's not gonna work because I've done that. Could you please help me?

Comment: As far as I know that is not possible.

Comment: Python never considers lists to "wrap around", the concept of "from 5 wrapping around to 2" is unknown.

Comment: saying *"...output would be: `[6, 1, 2]`..."* would make me read your question fewer times.

Comment: I wonder if one could tweak [`itertools.cycle()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) to get the desired output

Comment: The question is unclear : do you want to remove things between index 1 and 5 (as your expected ouput shows) or start from 5 and loop back to 0 ?

Comment: @jadsq Sorry for ambiguity , I wanted to slice it starting from index 5 then loop back to 0 ..

Comment: Please edit the expected output then. As you can see people answering are strictly following your example.

Comment: @healthyPAPAYA So you want `[1,2,6]` or `[6,1,2]`?

Comment: I've edited it. sorry.

Comment: @healthyPAPAYA Alright, good show. That was a waste of these poor peoples' time though. You can take a look at my answer.

Comment: @Coldspeed you need to undelete it ;)

Comment: @mkrieger1 Haha already done mate.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I'm aware, doing this without writing your own custom code doesn't seem possible. Python doesn't wrap lists around.

You can create a custom generator to do what you want, though:

```
>>> def cycle(l, start=0):
...     l = l[start:] + l[:start]
...     while True:
...         x = l.pop(0)
...         yield x
...         l.append(x)
... 
>>> k = cycle(a, 5)
>>> next(k)
6
>>> next(k)
1
>>> next(k)
2
```

(*Example rolled back due to OP's post change.*)

Here's an improved version that will take into account the number elements you want to get from the generator:

```
>>> def cycle(l, start=0, iters=None):
...     l = l[start:] + l[:start]
...     i = 0
...     while True:
...         if iters is not None and i == iters:
...             raise StopIteration
...         x = l.pop(0)
...         yield x
...         l.append(x)
...         i += 1
... 
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> list(cycle(a, start=5, iters=3))
[6, 1, 2]
```

Comment: They want `1, 2, 6`, not `6, 1, 2`.

Comment: Looks like it was a typo and they did actually want `6, 1, 2`

Comment: @jadsq LOL. No matter. Doing a rollback is simple.

Comment: easier to use `itertools.cycle` with `itertools.islice`

Comment: @Chris_Rands With `itertools.cycle` you have less flexibility.

Comment: How is it less flexible?

Comment: @Chris_Rands Try `list(itertools.cycle(l))` and see what happens.

Comment: try: `list(islice(cycle(arr), start, len(arr)+end+1))`

Comment: It's readable enough IMO; just some wrapper around: iterable,start,end ...it should also be faster

Comment: If you are only going to output a certain number of elements(second example) why do you need to make a copy of every element?

Comment: @Baldrickk That's a valid nitpick, and I don't know how to overcome it without sacrificing on simplicity, in which case I may as well fall back to using Chris' solution.

Comment: I've just added a generator function to my answer that solves it, by iterating through the list in place.

Answer (score 2):

Update:

Rotate left n elements (or right for negative n) and slice number of element you want

```
L = L[n:] + L[:n] # rotate left n elements
```

In ur case n is 5:

```
>>> output = arr[5:] + arr[:5]
>>> output[:3]
[6, 1, 2]
```

Previous

```
>>> arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> output = arr[:]
>>> del output[2:5]
>>> output
[1, 2, 6]
>>>
```

Comment: @Coldspeed `6,1,2` not `6,2,1`

Comment: This creates a new list the same size as the first, then slices _that_.  Isn't that a bit inefficient?

Comment: inefficient only if u comparing with output = arr[5:] + arr[:2]

Comment: That is what I would compare it with...   what if the list is in the order of GB in size?

Comment: Don't worry, coldspeed has the same problem.  Though his excuse is that his generator can potentially produce an arbitary number of elements.

Answer (score 1):

Create a function to slice the input array for you and append the two parts together to get the desired list.

```
def cyc_slice(lst, start, n): 
    return lst[start:] + lst[:(start+n)%len(lst)]
```

Unlike both other answers, this doesn't make a superflous copy of all the list elements that you don't want.

```
>>> arr=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
>>> cyc_slice(arr, 5, 3)
[6, 1, 2]
```

And an improved iterator solution:

```
def cycle(l, start=0, n=None):
    if not l:
        return
    idx = start-1
    end = (idx + n) % len(l) if n else -1
    while idx != end:
        idx+=1
        try:
            x = l[idx]
        except IndexError:
            idx = 0
            x = l[idx]
        yield x
```

when provided with a count, it will provide that many elements. Otherwise, it can keep looping.  This iterates through the list in place, so doesn't allocate any elements to memory (unless you create a list from it)

```
>>> list(cycle(arr,5,3))
[6, 1, 2]
```